# mod_python.publisher: nothing to publish

Tags: python, mod-python

HI,
I get the following error on executing a script:

```
[Thu Jul 15 17:32:02 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_python.publisher: nothing to publish., referer: http://localhost/test/mptest.py/ff
```

What does this mean and how can I resolve this?

Comment: You appear to have completely neglected to give us any information that would help us to answer this question: mod_python configuration, the code of the relevant script, what you're doing, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's some useful information

[mod_python publisher](http://www.modpython.org/pipermail/mod_python/2004-May/015652.html)